# Inheriting attributes from a parent class function without executing the rest of the parent class function

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I would only like to execute print function from class Two, while I want to inherit only the attribute self.name from class One without printing it's function. Is it possible to have only output as "Test John" without printing just "John" before that?

This is the code:

```
class One:
def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'John'
    print(self.name)

class Two(One):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print('Test ' + self.name)

two = Two()
```

And this is the output:

```
John
Test John
```

I would like to have my output like this (just the second line):

```
Test John
```

...without having to change my code (without deleting my print function in class One).

Comment: Even if it’s somehow possible to hack this it’s a **really bad idea** because your derived class is violating the contract of the parent class. Don’t do this. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Better to leave I/O side effects out of `__init__` *altogether*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Konrad Rudolph and chepner have said, it's bad practice to do io at the constructor but if you really need to do this then:
You can add a type test at the constructor of class One so that only if you initialize a One object **directly** `John` will be printed:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'John'
        if type(self)==One:
            print(self.name)

class Two(One):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Test ' + self.name)

two = Two()
```

Comment: So please share your specific requirements and I'll try to help